# Select files from IEnumerable<>

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following:

```
var selectedFilesToReplace = new List<string>();
foreach (string file in files) 
{
    selectedFilesToReplace.AddRange(listUploadedFiles
        .Where(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x) == file));
}
```

that fill the selectedFilesToReplace collection with a set of FULL path files.
I need to select only the file name with its extension.

Is this possible in a single Linq expression?

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
selectedFilesToReplace.AddRange(listUploadedFiles
    .Where(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x) == file))
    .Select(p => Path.GetFileName(p));
```

In C# 4, you can also write

```
selectedFilesToReplace.AddRange(listUploadedFiles
    .Where(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x) == file))
    .Select(Path.GetFileName);
```

Comment: I have not yet switched C# 4; is it the case that the "Return Type Inference Does Not Work On Method Groups" restriction has been lifted?


http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/05/c-3-0-return-type-inference-does-not-work-on-member-groups.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
var fileNameOnly = selectedFilesToReplace.Select(Path.GetFileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter implementation as a single expression:

```
 var selectedFilesToReplace = 
   listUploadedFiles.Where(
      f => files.Contains(
        Path.FileNameWithoutExtension(f)))
          .ToList();
```

Though IMHO the `.ToList()` is probably just superfluous.